# Alternative to "in" expression for iterating over objects polymer (0.5.4)

Tags: polymer, web-component

Using the repeat and in expression it is trivial to iterate over arrays, but swapping

```
            this.data = ["foo","bar"];
```

to

```
            this.data = {foo:"football",bar:"barfly"}
```

fails to iterate over the object. I have seen examples of using Object.key in order to get each value, but the index returned is 0,1 instead of "foo" "bar".

While this simple example doesn't use 2 way binding, I would like to keep support for it, in case I need it in the future.

http://jsbin.com/copogeyome/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Polymer</title>
    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
<polymer-element name="an-consumer" attributes="data" noscript>
    <template>testing {{data.foo}}<br>
        <template id="foo">f {{}}<br></template>
        <template id="bar">b {{}}<br></template>
        <template id="0">0 {{}}<br></template>
        <template id="1">1 {{}}<br></template>
        <template id="2">2 {{}}<br></template>
        {
        <template repeat="{{obj,index in data}}" bind="{{data}}">
            ( {{index}} - {{obj}} ) = <template ref="{{index}}" bind="{{obj}}"></template>
        </template>
        }
    </template>
</polymer-element>
<polymer-element name="an-supplier" attributes="data">
    <template></template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        ready: function(){
            this.data = ["foo","bar"];
            //this.data = {foo:"football",bar:"barfly"}
        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
<polymer-element name = "an-root" noscript>
    <template>
        <an-supplier data="{{stuff}}"></an-supplier>
        <an-consumer data="{{stuff}}"></an-consumer>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
<an-root>
</an-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is [yet] no built-in ability to iterate over object, you might easily achieve this functionality with *filter*:

```
<template repeat="{{key in data | getKeys}}">
  <span>Key: {{key}}</span>
  <span>Value: {{data[key]}}</span>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
  ready: function(){
    // this.data = ["foo","bar"];
    this.data = {foo:"football",bar:"barfly"}
  }
  // filter function to use in looping objects
  getKeys : function(o) {
    return Object.keys(o);
  }
});
</script>
```

Whether you have additional questions, please, don’t hesitate to ask.

Live: http://jsbin.com/munehitogu/1/edit

Comment: What happens when the data changes?

Comment: `repeat` is re-executed. I’ve added a link to live preview.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ficimeqari/1/ I've added a task that I think should be repeating changing the data.

Comment: You can’t call `startUpdater` without specification of the object it belongs to. `this.startUpdater();` instead does the trick. When you call `startUpdater`  _Polymer_ looks up the function in the global namespace.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/munehitogu/1/ Has an edited version for anyone else that stumbles across this question in the future. Works fine at least from the supplier to the consumer, unsure if data could flow the other way however.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I edited the answer to include a link to your modified live version. “at least from the supplier to the consume”—they are absolutely symmetric in the example; of course the other way round it works as well.